# Fedora's Gnome Terminal's Monospace font changed?

Tags: fedora, gnome-terminal, mate-desktop

I was running Fedora 34 until now. Fedora 38 came out and I moved to that. I'm using MATE with Gnome Terminal. The font is set to Monospace 13 in both systems. Yet there's a difference in the font. What I don't like in Fedora 38. How could I have the same font like I had in Fedora 34? The change can be seen especially on "r"

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Monospace" is not a real font; it's merely an alias to some or other font, which traditionally used to be **DejaVu Sans Mono** on Linux for about a decade – with the distinct flattened @ shape as in your "original" screenshot.

(DejaVu fonts weren't really *great* fonts though, merely decent, but for a long time there weren't any better FOSS fonts available, especially for a distro such as Fedora that was strongly concerned with licensing. However, now that more free fonts exist, it is not surprising that Fedora has changed the default.)

If you run `fc-match Monospace` you will see the current mapping.

> How could I have the same font like I had in Fedora 34?

First, *install* the fonts. Fedora no longer includes DejaVu by default, so install `dejavu-sans-fonts` via DNF (or download them [from GitHub](https://github.com/dejavu-fonts/dejavu-fonts/releases) into your `~/.local/share/fonts/`).

Once installed, just change the terminal font through GNOME Terminal's "Profiles > Default".

##### Changing font aliases system-wide

Within GNOME, the `org.gnome.desktop.interface` `monospace-font-name` GSetting might be the one that controls the alias system-wide (although of course you can just change it for the terminal alone; it's fine to use one monospace font for terminals and another for normal text).

- GNOME Tweaks > Fonts > Monospace Text
- regedit: `dconf-editor` > /`org`/`gnome`/`desktop`/`interface`/`monospace-font-name`
- `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name "Something 11"`

Outside of GNOME, such aliases are defined via Fontconfig (e.g. `/etc/fonts/conf.d`). For example, create a `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` that contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "urn:fontconfig:fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>

    <alias>
        <family>Monospace</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>DejaVu Something Or Other</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>

</fontconfig>
```

as documented in `man fonts.conf`.

Comment: This is the fc-match output for 34: `DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"` and for 38: `NotoSansMono[wght].ttf: "Noto Sans Mono" "Regular"`

Comment: Oh, so they [did switch to Noto fonts for everything](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/DefaultToNotoFonts). I thought that was only for (sans-)serif. Point remains, change your terminal to use DejaVu Sans Mono if you want the old font.

Comment: could you please drop me the exact command to be executed? I don't want to ruin something,

Comment: If you only want it for the terminal, just do it through the terminal's graphical settings. If you want it system-wide, install GNOME Tweaks and change it from there. (Or failing that, install dconf-editor which is the "GNOME regedit".)

Comment: yes, I want it only for the terminal, but I cannot see such an option in the settings... :(

Comment: For GNOME Terminal you change the font individually for each "profile", so under "Preferences > Profiles > Default > [✔] Custom font". (Or via dconf-editor under /org/gnome/terminal; it's a particularly annoying place to access via CLI.)

Comment: If I go to Preferences->... ->Custom font, then I will see only those aliases, like: Liberation Mono, MathjaxVector, ..., Monospace, Nimbus Mono. But where to input that DejaVu?

Comment: Then perhaps DejaVu fonts are _not installed anymore_ in Fedora 38? Install `dejavu-sans-fonts` via dnf (or whatever Fedora now uses). Alternatively, download the latest version of the TTF's [from github](https://github.com/dejavu-fonts/dejavu-fonts/releases) and drop them into ~/.local/share/fonts/, and they will appear in the list.

Comment: oh my god, indeed, they are not installed, thanks for your help :)